# Package.json, add local directory to node-modules

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json

I have local library for some graphs and I need add it to node_modules. Is there any way how to add this library using package.json?

Our package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.01.01",
  "scripts": {
   ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
   ...
  },
   ...
}
```

I mean to add something like:

```
  "directory": {
    "my-library": "./src/path/to/my/lib"
  }
```

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation you can define your local directories as dependencies in the following format:

```
{
  "name": "baz",
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
  }
}
```

You can read more here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

Comment: I tried that, but have:
_npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Nuvia\Project1\ims-core-frontend\app\src\app\shared\graphs\amchart-graph\library_

It is correct? That **file:**, when I have directory?

Comment: The library has to be a nodejs package.

Comment: hmm, i think it isn't, surely I am not make nodejs package. Try find how to make it

Comment: Short version: run "npm init" in your C:\Nuvia\Project1\ims-core-frontend\app\src\app\shared\graphs\amchart-graph\library directory.

Comment: thanks, I create package by npm init and now have this library in node_modules, THANKS